# How to remove a vnet0 interface?

Tags: centos, networking, network-interface, bridge

In troubleshooting a no connectivity issue on a newly rolled out kvm host machine, I'm noticing a second bridge interface that isn't needed and may have been created previously:  vnet0

```
[user@box]# brctl show
bridge name              bridge id           STP enabled  interfaces
br0                      8000.14187769b69a   no           em1
                                                          vnet0
virbr0                   8000.5254003ada63   yes          virbr0-nic

[user@box]# ip route
default via 111.111.111.2 dev br0
169.254.0.0/16 dev br0 scope link metric 1006
111.111.111.0/23 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 111.111.111.44
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src src 192.168.122.1
```

Here is the ifcfg-br0 and em1 files respectively:

```
[user@box ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0 
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=static
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
NAME=br0
PREFIX=23
DEVICE=br0
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=111.111.111.44
GATEWAY=111.111.111.2
DNS1=4.4.4.4

[user@box ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1
TYPE=Ethernet
NM_CONTROLLED=no
NAME=em1
DEVICE=em1
ONBOOT=yes
BRIDGE=br0
```

A sister EL7 system with fully functioning network bridge looks like this:

```
[user@box]# brctl show
bridge name              bridge id           STP enabled  interfaces
br0                      8000.141877699b     no           em1
virbr0                   8000.5254004bc0f4   yes          virbr0-nic

[user@box]# ip route
default via 111.111.111.2 dev br0 
111.111.111.0/23 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 111.111.111.222
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1 

[user@box ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0 
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=static
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
NAME=br0
PREFIX=23
DEVICE=br0
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=111.111.111.222
GATEWAY=111.111.111.2
DNS1=4.4.4.4

[user@box ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1
TYPE=Ethernet
NM_CONTROLLED=no
NAME=em1
DEVICE=em1
ONBOOT=yes
BRIDGE=br0
```

I tried using `virsh net-destroy vnet0`, but am seeing `failed to get network vnet0`

How do I remove the rougue `vnet0` interface from the first example?

Answer (score 0):

To disable virbr0, try:

> virsh net-destroy default
>
> virsh net-undefine default
>
> service libvirtd restart
>
> ifconfig